# In proving that $f(w)f(v) = vw$ as an orthogonal transformation, why does $v^T = v$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've a proof that says if $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, ~ v \mapsto Av$, where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then for $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have $f(w)f(v) = (Av)(Aw) = (Av)^T(Aw) = v^TA^TAw = v^Tw = vw$. This is from the proof that the map is an isometry. Could someone explain the last step? It seems to be saying $v^T = v$ but I'm not sure how that's true. Thanks.

Comment: Is $vw$ supposed to be dot product? It is not true in a technical sense that $v=v^T$; one will be a row vector and the other a column vector

Comment: It is just a change in notation :) $v^T w$ is seen as the matrix product of the row $v^T$ with the column $w$, but this is the same thing as the dot product of the two vectors, which is often just written as $vw$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I actually missed the dot in the last step, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be some confusion in general going on. E.g. $f(w)$ and $f(v)$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that $f(w)f(v)$ does not make sense in a matrix/vector multiplication way, as we'd try to calculate the matrix product

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}$$

which is ill-defined.

There is however one way I could read the statement, namely involving the classical dot product over real vectors, where you'd have the relationship $v\cdot w=v^\top w$. Then, to write this out with the standard notation for the dot product, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, you'd have:

$$
\langle f(w),f(v)\rangle=\langle Aw,Av\rangle=(Aw)^\top(Av)=w^\top A^\top Av=w^\top v=\langle w,v\rangle
$$

**EDIT:** Note, that there is a slight twist in the way you wrote it, if I'm not mistaken. This makes also sense as note that $f$ is a so called *orthogonal transformation*, i.e. it is a linear transformation that additionally preserves a corresponding scalar product, i.e. it is an *isometry* of the standard euclidean vector space $(\mathbb{R}^3,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ and thus preserves lengths, angles, etc.

Preservation of the scalar product means exactly that $\langle w,v\rangle=\langle f(w),f(v)\rangle$ for all $w,v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and you with this verified the statement that an orthogonal matrix induces an orthogonal map. There is actually(up to orthonormal bases), a 1-to-1 correspondence between orthogonal maps and orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. Appreciate it.